# Modify Page url using TBB

Tags: publishing, templating

We have created and implemented a TBB which modifies the published Page's url. We managed to modify the Page url in the Package, but the Broker database it still shows the unmodified page url.

- original: /hotel/{test}
- modified: /hotel/testing

We have 2 items in the Package:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are altering the Page Package item and not the Output JSON... but in any case, what you are trying to achieve is not possible using templating.

You can however override the Page publish url using a Deployer extension, but why do you want to do that in the first place? I have the feeling that that's asking for trouble, ie. you will be breaking the 'View on Site' functionality, not to mention you will cause confusion for the content editors, just two counter arguments from the top of my head.

Comment: Basically we are trying to insert keyword key in page url in Tridion just by instering the keyword key in structure group directory and it will create page with url: /hotelA/{test} where test will be the keyword key and when it is published we want to replace with keyword description. We are doing this process because want to have control over the url path name. we are sending the keyword for language translation and for different languages just by changing the keyword description we will have control over all the structure group directory value which means it will change the url.

Comment: how can we use deploy extension to overide page url? do you have any documentation about deploy extension . im a bit new to deployer extension .

Comment: @Binod The official docs (https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-4CDF2D46-80F7-413F-9D51-A091299CC8BE) is a good starting point and there are a lot of blogs/resources out there also, so you should manage. I see that you have asked a specific question here: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20926/step-to-overide-publishing-page-url-using-deployer-extension so as far as this one is concerned, consider accepting the answer so the question "becomes closed".