# Step to overide publishing page url using deployer extension

Tags: templating, sdl-tridion, deployer

Anybody knows how to create deployer extension to change publishing page URL before inserting to broker database?

We are trying to modify the page URL because we will be using keyword key value in tridion which can be achieve by 
adding the keyword key in structure group directory  that needs to be replaced by that keyword description value.

By adding keyword in page URL we will able to translate only 1 unique Slug - allow for send of 1 unique SLUG (e.g 'contact') that will be referenced/propagated across all areas required as opposed to managing different versions of 'contact' for each individual hotel.

What we want to achive.
In tridion: hotesA/room1/{key}/
In broker: hotesA/room1/description/

we tried using templating just by changing the package item page wont do the job.

Any other posible solution to achieve this process of changing url will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend modifying the published URL generated within SDL since you *could* face some consequences with Link resolution.

Have you considered implementing a simple URLRewrite module (dotnet or java) for your web application? Consider a Rewrite and not a Redirect for a user and SEO friendly experience.

Try to look for pattens in the URLs to govern them seamlessly. If they change frequenctly, a solution would be for you to publish the Rewrite patterns from SDL and have an action in your web application to refresh your Rewrites.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by extending com.tridion.deployer.Module and overriding the process method. Be aware that it isn't trivial. This method starts with the entire publish package, and you need to do quite a bit of digging through xml files and other files in the package to achieve your goal.

Also, if you want the 'view on site' functionality to continue to work, you also need to implement the GetPublishUrlEventArgs event.

Sounds like a nice little project. But the good news is: I know it can be done because I did something like this for a customer a few years back.

Comment: As there are various pipeline in deployer-conf.xml which pipeline needs to be modify to achive my goal?
or it is different for this case?

Comment: I created a new step in the Tridion-Process-Deploy pipeline, before the PageDeploy step.

Comment: Good to know the View On Site event subscription :).